# Compute Engine Label Information in Google Cloud Billing CSV file

Tags: billing, google-cloud-platform

In Google Cloud Billing CSV file ,I see none of the Labels associated with the Compute Engines appear in the billing CSV file .
It only has a field named 'Project Labels'.
Is there any way to configure google cloud billing ,so that resource specific labels also appear in the exported CSV ?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/12/use-labels-to-gain-visibility-into-GCP-resource-usage-and-spending.html resource specific labels are only available if you enable export of billing data to Big Query.

From there you can construct you own queries to group the data as you like.